# What to look for in Chanuka flames

Tags: menora-chanukia, chanuka, oil, shulchan-aruch, halacha

In determining the preferableness of fuel and wick types, the שולחן ערוך and רמ"א [refer](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%92_%D7%90) to light "hanging on wicks nicely" and the possibility of candle light being "clean" and "clear". What physical states of burning wick/fuel do these phrases describe?

Is a comparison of light "clarity" or the other parameters listed above relevant with the modern home pyrotechnology of today or is it a moot point because the standard materials used automatically exceed the necessary threshholds?

(This question is motivated by a cryptic but direct פסק I got recently from a prominent American פוסק that, as far as the רמ"א's opinion is concerned, wax candle flames are not clearer than oil flames.)

Comment: Maybe the wax candles today are improved compared to those in the times of the Ramah?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the goal is for the light to be fairly steady, and not constantly flickering because of impurities in the fuel or wick.

I think that (assuming you use standard store-bought ingredients) the light will definitely meet or exceed the necessary threshold.

If you are making your own, I guess you should avoid making candles out of discarded flax scraps and gourd oil.  Although even if you do, you will fulfill your obligation.

Comment: Shoot! Now what I am supposed to do with all my gourd oil?